# which is the correct version of akka-actor-typed to use with Spark 3.5.0?

Tags: apache-spark, gpu, akka, rapids

I keep receiving this error,

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: akka/actor/typed/ActorRef",
```

when I try to deploy my application.jar in one active Spark cluster by:

```
spark-submit --class RED.Main --master spark://localhost:7077 application.jar
```

Why is it so? Do I have incompatible versions of Akk-actor typed (2.8.5) and Spark (3.5.0)?

Comment: Could you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Provide details about the tool you are using to pack your app in a jar, commands used, the configuration of the project to build it

Comment: I don't think Spark has any dependencies on Akka at all anymore.